# <!> Error during startup: Cannot load library in OMNET++ project while using sqlite3

Tags: c++, eclipse, sqlite, omnet++

I have an OMNET++ project, *CSW*, that references other OMNET++ projects via **Project->Properties->Project** References.

The reference to the project *CB_CSW_Vehicle* works fine. I marked for this project **Project->Properties->OMNET++->Makemake->Options->Target** as **shared library**. So I have a *libCB_CSW_Vehicle.dll*, which is used by the main project *CSW*. Simulations from *CSW* run, using *CB_CSW_Vehicle* without problems.

The reference to the other project *CB_CSW_Cloud*, doesn't work. I made the same steps for it:

1. marked **"create shared library"** in **OMNET++->Makemake->Options->Target**
2. checked the project *CB_CSW_Cloud* in **Properties->Project References** of the main project

I can build my main project *CSW*. I can also build *libCB_CSW_Cloud.dll*. When I run a simulation from project *CSW*, I receive an error:

```
<!> Error during startup: Cannot load library '../../../CB_CSW_Cloud/src//libCB_CSW_Cloud.dll': The operation completed successfully.
```

The only difference between these two projects, is that *CB_CSW_Cloud* uses **sqlite3** library. I added it to the project with following steps:

1. set **Project->Properties->OMNET++->Makemake->Options->Link->Additional Libraries to link with (-l option)**: *sqlite3*
2. set **Project->Properties->C/C++General->Paths And Symbols->Library Paths**: *C:/sqlite*

Since I don't receive some exact information, why *libCB_CSW_Cloud* was not loaded, I don't know what causes the problem. I use it in exactly the same way, as other project *CB_CSW_Vehicle*, that works. This leads me to the suggestion, that the **sqlite3** library causes the problem. Is it possible? Can a project *CSW* have a reference to the other project *CB_CSW_Cloud*, that itself uses a library *sqlite3*? Or shall I also add this library to *CSW*?

Can you help me to run the *CSW* project?

**Update**: I solved my problem with adding sqlite3 library to the run configuration and copying the source code of the *CB_CSW_Cloud* and *CB_CSW_Vehicle* projects to the *CSW* project. It is really difficult in OMNET++ to have a lot of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add link to the `sqlite3` library in **run** configuration of `CSW` project. Go to `Run` | `Run Configurations...` | `Main` tab | `More>>` and in `Dynamic libraries` write path to `sqlite3` library. Please note that the path has to be relative to the working directory, and without a `dll` suffix, without a `lib` prefix.
 If the `dll` file of `sqlite3` doesn't contain `lib` prefix, try to rename it (for example from `sqlite3.dll` into `libsqlite3.dll`).

Comment: If I add my path to the `${opp_shared_libs:/CBCSWSim/simulations/avspeedaggreg/path}` I receive an error, that it is not an existing folder or file.

Comment: The error is: `argument to ${opp_shared_libs} needs to be an existing file, folder, or project`

Comment: The path has to contain a filename. For example: if you want to load library `c:\sqlite3\libfoo.dll`, and your working directory is `c:\omnetpp\CBCSWSim\simulations\avspeedaggreg`, then you should just write: `../../../../sqlite3/foo`, without `${opp_shared_libs:....`.

Comment: When I try to find the libsqlite3.dll on my pc, I receive an error  `Cannot determine location for ../../../../../../../sqlite/sqlite3`, so I just copied it to my working directory and wrote `sqlite3`. It produces no errors. So, as long, as I don't use functions from `CB_CSW_Cloud`, simulation is running, but when I call a constructor of a class from `CB_CSW_Cloud`, I have error `Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741511`. I don't know if it is still `sqlite3` problem or something else. Is it possible to have some more info about this error in OMNETT++?

Comment: You can obtain more information about error provided that you compile both projects in debug mode. Then in `omnetpp.ini` set: `debug-on-errors=true` and prepare debug configuration (in the same way as run configuration). Then start debug. The debugger should stop executing of your code when an error occurs. And you should be able to view the lines of code which cause this error.

Comment: Thank you, now I see an error in DEBUG mode, if I use a function from `CB_CSW_Cloud`. It's `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.`