# Importing external library to Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

Morning,

I would like to import my own library to Veins (v4.4) project.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) to compile a shared library. 
I've also stripped the shared library with this command:

```
strip --strip-unneeded libfoo.so
```

since I've noticed that system libraries such as sqlite3 are compiled in stripped mode.

Then I imported the library from

1.Project->Properties->Paths and Symbols :

1.1 includes

1.2 Libraries

1.3 Library Paths

2.Makemake-> Src->Options->Link-> Additional Libraries

However, the problem is that when I use the imported library I still get an error of "undefined symbol "; so I suppose the library is not correctly imported or read by the simulator.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you get an error while compiling, while linking, or while running?

Comment: while running: 
<!> Warning: opp_run: Cannot check library ../../src/veins: ../../src//libveins.so: undefined symbol: _Z3foov

<!> Error during startup: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.so': ../../src//libveins.so: undefined symbol: _Z3foov.

Comment: What command line parameters are you using to run the simulation?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I run it form the IDE, not from command line. If I run it in debug mode I get this "$1 = 0xff
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Inferior 1 (process 4837) exited with code 01]
Quit"

Answer (score 0):

How to load additional libraries in your simulation is documented in the [user manual's chapter on running simulations](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:run-sim:loading-extra-libraries).

In brief, you will need to add `-l foo` to the command line parameters to make the simulation load `libfoo.so` when it starts.

If you use the IDE to start the simulation, you can edit your simulation's run configuration: Choose menu item `Run > Run Configurations...`, then on the `Main` tab click on `More >>`, append the name of your library (e.g. `foo` if your library is called `libfoo.so`, or `foo bar` if you want your simulation to load `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` on startup) to the `Dynamic libraries` text field. After launching, you will see the aforementioned command line parameter `-l foo` being used by the IDE to run the simulation.

If you are unsure about where to put your library, a related question has a discussion on this: [<!> Error during startup: Cannot load library in OMNET++ project while using sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32695871/4707703)

Comment: How to append the library to the veins one in the Dynamic libraries field? Beacuse I already did all the other steps in the correct way; this could be the only one which causes my simulation not to run properly. Does it need a semicolumn, coma, copying the lib in the veins project,etx? I really tried lots of stuffs, but it doesn't work, although I can use sqlite3 library without any problem.

Comment: Dynamic libraries : ${opp_shared_libs:/veins/examples/veins} foo , but still getting error of "undefined symbol" . I also tried with foo inside brackets, but it doesn't work.